# Distinguish between two entry points of the method

Tags: c#, events

The are three interfaces: `IServer, IComponent, IClient.` The connection between them is done through events. I write `Server, Component, Client`  classes which implement them respectively.

Between the components there may be dependencies. That is if component y dependent on x then when `x.Start()` invoked - all descendants `Start()` are invoked. The dependency is created by `AddDependency()` method which is in `IComponent`. (see source code link below).

Clients can't see components directly and interact with them through the server, using the events. This is done, only after all components and clients are registered on the server.

Problem:
The method `Start()` has 2 entry points:
1: `Start()` invoked in `Server` event handler (1'st component)
2: `Start()` invoked in `Component` event handler (descendant is started).

For 1: if status of component is already `Running` - throw `IllegalOperationException`
For 2: if descendant is already `Running` - do nothing.

How to distinguish between 1 and 2?

Restrictions:
- Modifying interfaces - forbidden
- Downcasting - forbidden.

The one solution that I see - is put static flag, which falls down right after the `Start()` for 1'st component is invoked. However this approach destroys encapsulation, because the flag is should be reinitialized each time in some "external" method (e.g. in server's handler) so the external method has to see something more than what is specified in interface. Also this is implicitly implies that the Start() is invoked only by Server, which is not guaranteed in the problem.

Any more ideas?

Sources:
http://rghost.net/38868270

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your question boils down to "I have an interface which just has a start method, how can I tell if it is already started without adding anything else".

The answer strikes me that you can't. What you could do is always throw `IllegalOperationException` no matter how it is called. Then in your component you catch the `IllegalOperationException` and pass on (do nothing). In your server method you let it bubble up to the more relevant location.

As far as I can think this is the only option you have given your restrictions.

Note: I did not look at any of the code since I didn't want to download a zip file with 9 files in it from an untrustworthy source (no offence to you personally).